# COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

```
mysql> SELECT LOCATE("n", "München") COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

How do I get rid of this error?

What I already tried (copy&paste):

```
$ mysql -u admin -p $DATABASE
Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.1.69 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT LOCATE("n", "München") COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
mysql> SET NAMES utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOCATE("n", "München") COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
mysql> SELECT LOCATE(_utf8"n", _utf8"München") COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set_database";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the server has been compiled with a default character set of **binary**, so that string literals are being interpreted as such, or the client is set to use a binary mode when communicating with the server. You can change the client and connection character set by calling `SET NAMES utf8` (though this is not recommended if your SQL statements are being issued from PHP, for example, as PHP will have its own commands for setting the connection character set). See [Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html) in the MySQL reference manual.

Alternatively you can use "introducers" to specify explicitly the charset used for the string literals in your **LOCATE** function, for instance:

```
LOCATE(_utf8"n", _utf8"München")
```

See the reference manual page [Character String Literal Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-literal.html) for more details.

Comment: Which table? My query does not reference a table.

Comment: Sorry, half asleep here. I've replaced the answer completely.

Comment: Already before asking the question, I tried `SET NAMES utf8`, and now again, without success. The *introducers* look like a nice solution, but they dont't work: The error message persists. I tried: `SELECT LOCATE(_utf8"n", _utf8"München") COLLATE utf8_general_ci` By the way, I am directly using the console, to play around. I started the console with: `mysql -u admin -p $database` I just ran `show variables like "character_set_database"`. Result: `utf8`

Comment: I am wondering, why does the collation matter? LOCATE should return a numeric result, so you surely can't vary the order of a set of one integer?

Comment: I now added copy&pasted an example session into my question.

Answer (score 2):

The `COLLATE` in my example [sets the collation of the return value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) of
`LOCATE`, the result of which is of type `binary`.

To set the collation of the arguments:

```
mysql> SELECT LOCATE(_utf8"n" COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
                     _utf8"München" COLLATE utf8_general_ci) AS locate;
+--------+
| locate |
+--------+
|      3 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My motivation actually was finding out whether MySQL takes the collation
into account when searching for the substring. Unfortunately it does
*not*. See the result of the second command:

```
mysql> SELECT LOCATE(_utf8"ü" COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
                     _utf8"München" COLLATE utf8_general_ci) AS locate;
+--------+
| locate |
+--------+
|      2 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOCATE(_utf8"u" COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
                     _utf8"München" COLLATE utf8_general_ci) AS locate;
+--------+
| locate |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Test with a temporary table (collation taken into account in `WHERE` clause, but not in
`LOCATE`):

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test
       (text VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES("München");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT text FROM test WHERE text LIKE "%u%";
+---------+
| text    |
+---------+
| München |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOCATE("u", text) AS locate FROM test WHERE text LIKE "%u%"; 
+--------+
| locate |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I hope it helps someone. I kept getting the same error and I knew my charsets and collations were fine.

Check for '@' symbols in your statement that don't belong.  I was testing my stored procedure out as a select statement with variables, then when creating the stored proc forgot to remove the '@' symbols. Needless to say, I felt very silly.

I also know this doesn't seem to be the case in this question but this is my first SO post and I don't have enough rep to do much else, so I apologize.